# Can I shrink or expand text according to browser resolution

Tags: html, css, font-size, adjustable

Can I shrink or expand text according to browser resolution just using html and css?

Basically I want to create a website which is compatible with 1024x768 and 320x480. I managed everything to shrink to size (images, video) but I wasn't able to find a way to shrink the text from 1024x768 to 320x480.

Has anyone got a simple solution to this? Has anyone had the same problem?

I'm open to any ideas which involve css3 and html5, I dont't want to use anything else javascript,jquery. That are the specifications given to me.

Comment: Personally I think one of the best options for make a mobile compatible site is using bootstrap3. Might be a little bit of a learning curve since there is so much info, but I think it is well worth it. http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
    body { font-size: 12px;}
}
```

to set different rules for different resolutions

And add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` to the html head, since otherwise some mobile browsers will evaluate the css pixels as if they had a bigger screen resolution (in order to display pages designed for bigger screens more or less correctly).

Comment: so I could use @media handheld to set it for 320x480?

Comment: I am not sure: there are handheld devices with significantly bigger resolution.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 defines the unit [`vw`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths) which is suitable for this purpose. `vw` is 1% of the viewport's width, which can make it hard to guess the right size. However, it's extremely useful for sizing text over a scalable background image, for example.

Use it like any of the more familiar units, e.g.

```
h1 { font-size:3vw; }
p, li { font-size:1.5vw; }
```

You can also couple it with a media query to provide a minimum text size.

The [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths) defines other relative size units:

> ‘`rem`’:   font size of the root element
>   ‘`vw`’:    1% of viewport's width
>   ‘`vh`’:    1% viewport's height
>   ‘`vmin`’:  1% of viewport's smaller dimension
>   ‘`vmax`’:  1% of viewport's larger dimension